# Generating individual constructor for a model in EMF

Tags: model, emf, ecore

EMF generates classes with empty/"super()" constructors.
My question is, whether it is possible to say that the constructor of a specific class has to contain certain lines of code?
For example, initialize an identifier attribute of a class with an UUID?

Answer (score 2):

EMF uses the empty default constructor for de-serialization, so do not add anything in the generated classes' constructors.
It is common to have a helper class (or service or whatever design pattern you use) that calls the factory methods and do some initialization on the instances they create.